# Is doing Parent.call from the child object a right way to implement Inheritance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I came across this piece of code. It didn't look that right to me. Is this the right way to implement `super` in JavaScript? If not, what is the right way?

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;  
}

function Student(name){
  Person.call(this, name);
}

Student.prototype = new Person(); 
var a = new Student('test');
var b = new Student('test2');
```

Comment: don't implement inheritance in JavaScript - JavaScript gives you arbitrary depth lexical closures so you don't need to use inheritance to share data, data sharing is better done through explicit closure bindings I find. Faking a type system in JavaScript is step #1 towards having tons of runtime bugs in your JavaScript code

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: That is pure opinion without evidence to back it up. Personally, I find closures hard to unit test, thus raising the likelyhood that bugs crop up, negating your argument. The _real_ frustration with object oriented JavaScript in my opinion is that `this` shifts context depending on how the function was called.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I agree completely; Yes it's pure opinion, but I enjoy throwing it out there. Also your second issue: I work around it easily by never dealing with `this` -> just use closures. Yes I recognize they may make unit testing trickier but at that I must say unit testability I find to be more an affect of one's ability to modularize their code into side effect free and referentially transparent portions rather than the approach they use. The more referentially transparent your code, the easier it is to test, often times using inheritance precludes referential transparency though..

Comment: @JimmyHoffa what you're describing sounds to me like what Crockford calls "functional inheritance". I don't think that pattern deals with the "super" issue any more cleanly than prototypal inheritance, though. As far as I can tell this question is really about referencing the parent explicitly rather than having some kind of `super` keyword.

Comment: @Hey what I describe is an approach to get similar benefits to inheritance, but not to use it. I think there should be no prototypal or subtypal inheritance relationships as I find them to be footguns. As I mention above, it is an opinion, and is written in comments because it's not an answer to the asked question. Just a comment to share a different perspective on this problem with folks - one that says: Just don't solve this problem as it's been invented by a faulty solution (subtypal inheritance) to begin with. *That's just my opinion*

Answer (score 2):

This works and is the right way depending on whether or not the browser supports `Object.create`:

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

The `Object.create` method sets up prototypal inheritance without executing the constructor function `Person` when "inheriting."

Answer (score 1):

The first part is pretty common, it's just a way to get the constructor of the subtype to share the functionality of the supertype's constructor. Notice that `Person.call` doesn't invoke `Person` as a constructor here, it invokes it as a regular function using the `this` binding from the `Student` being constructed.

It's probably a bit more common to see it written like this:

```
Person.apply(this, arguments);
```

If you don't like the idea of writing the name of the parent constructor explicitly and are looking for something generic like "super" you could do this instead:

```
this.constructor.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
```

You don't usually see this, though, because it's pretty unwieldy and you probably already have a reference to the parent constructor at the point where you're doing this anyway.

---

The second part is widely regarded as being incorrect. Don't do this:

```
Student.prototype = new Person();
```

Do this instead.

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

`Object.create(Person.prototype)` gives you an object with `Person.prototype` in its prototype chain without executing the `Person` constructor (which could have side effects and is unnecessary).